# Input and biber

Tags: biber, input

I think it's a trivial question, but I cannot find the answer elsewhere. I am using a file to include other files through \input. Everything works fine except from bibliography, which does not work and if I use the BibTeX processing the following appears:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021) The top-level auxiliary
> file: main.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file
> main.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux I
> found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux (There were 3
> error messages)

The information about biblatex are given in the preamble file, and they work in normal standalone files. How should I do to have the bibliography printed through this method?

A MWE follows:

SETUP FILE

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
% !TeX root = Example.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

MAIN

```
  \input{setup}
    
    \begin{document}

      \input{Text}
    
    \clearpage
        
        \input{Biblio}
    
    \end{document}
```

Text file:

```
Hallo, \cite{Muller}
```

Biblio file:

```
\printbibliography
```

bibliography.bib file's contents:

```
@book{Muller,
editor = {Müller, Gotfried},
title = {Example},
publisher = {Someone},
address = {Somewhere}
}
```

Comment: `biber` and `bibtex` are two different applications. As you want biber you shouldn't call bibtex. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations to learn how to configure your editor to use biber.

Comment: as you are mentioning that it normally works: you are probably confusing your editor by hiding the `!BIB TS-program = biber` directive in a setup file.